# can't install get_cli flutter

Tags: flutter, get-cli

I want to install get_cli but when running the command below, error is found

> flutter pub global activate get_cli

the error

> Warning: Executable "get" runs "bin/get.dart", which was not found in get_cli.

> Warning: Executable "getx" runs "bin/get.dart", which was not found in get_cli.

I have entered the path below to the environment

> export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"

Answer (score 3):

You can downgrade to 1.6.0 with

```
dart pub global deactivate get_cli
dart pub global activate get_cli 1.6.
```

[Ref Github Issue](https://github.com/jonataslaw/get_cli/issues/168)

Answer (score 1):

dart pub global activate get_cli

Comment: I have tried it, the installation process was successful, but when I run the **get** command an error appears


/home/pc-name/.pub-cache/bin/get: 8: dart: not found

Comment: try adding path to your terminal profile

Answer (score 1):

Explanation of error occurred due to this reason=>

// to install get_cli 1.6.0 version for proper working instead of get_cli^1.7.1

//first  of all deactivate get, getx version of 1.7.1  then install get_cli ^1.6.0

Do the steps

step=1>
flutter pub global deactivate get

Step=2>
flutter pub global deactivate gets

step=3>
dart pub global activate get_cli ^1.6.0

//this will surely help you if you follow these steps

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

### it show essay

### Get CLI

Install it
You can install the package from the command line:

dart pub global activate get_cli

*ya*

flutter pub global activate get_cli

[if you use cmd to install getcli](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKByx.png)

if you install Get_Cli using cmd thenafter installtion  in cmd you show

- Pub installs executables into C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\bin
  that path set system  variables in  PATH add new PATH veriable PATH

if you use other  terminal then after installesion  go your file maneger

- C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\bin
  go  and check it  after copy  that path and create new system verible as normal.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Perhaps you need to turn on developer mode to support flutter command line input

Comment: You should use English.

Comment: Maybe you're right, English is more suitable for most programmers, but I think most programmers know how to turn on developer mode